# jquery select adjacent items if they are of a specific class name

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup and am doing some jQuery mouseovers and am going to set the background-color. I'd also like to set the background-color of the adjacent class if the class is a .list_spacer

I currently have:

```
<div class='lists_items'>
<div class='list_item'>info here</div>
<div class='list_spacer'></div>
<div class='list_item'>info here</div>
<div class='list_spacer'></div>
<div class='list_item'>info here</div>
<div class='list_spacer'></div>
<div class='list_item'>info here</div>
</div>

$('.list_item').on('mouseover',function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','yellow'); // <- yeah, the simplest possible scenario
});
```

And am thinking there must be some way of accessing adjacent divs and setting only if of a certain class but don't know how. Any ideas on how to do this? I only want to select if immediately before or after and has class of list_spacer

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could user `.prev` and `.next` methods to access adjacent tags.

Example:

```
$('.list_item').on('mouseover',function(){
  $(this).prev().css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

To access a certain class, use:

```
$('.list_item').on('mouseover',function(){
  $(this).prev('.list_spacer').css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

You also can access parent tags:

```
<div class='list_item'>
     <div class='list_spacer'></div>
</div>

$('.list_spacer').parent().css('background-color','yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.next('.list_spacer')` or `.prev('.list_spacer')`

```
$('.list_item').on('mouseover',function(){
   var $this = $(this);

    var $div = $this.prev('.list_spacer').length ? $this.prev('.list_spacer')
                                                 : $this.next('.list_spacer') ;

    $div.css('background-color','yellow'); // 
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/F4SdJ/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use border instead of background color as background color will not be reflected as the list has no content and width.

$(function(){
    $('.list_item').on('mouseover',function(){

```
$(this).css('background-color','yellow'); 

$(this).next('.list_spacer').css('border','1px solid green');

});
});
```